# Height is not added properly in the modal body when the modal is opened as a separate component using ng-bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5, ng-bootstrap

Height is not added properly in the modal body when the modal is opened as a separate component using ng-bootstrap.

Issue exist on below stackblitz link
[image]
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwqusl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal-component.ts

Working Example:
It was working as expected without a separate component.
[image]
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfpf81?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal-options.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmodal-options.html

Does anyone know about this issue?

Comment: Stackblitz doesnt have the issue please check!

Comment: @NarenMurali
I have updated the link in the question, could you please have a look
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwqusl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal-component.ts

Comment: @Jeson, your stackblitz works!! did you forget the `fullscreen: true` in your code or do you have another version of ng-bootstrap in your real project (fullscreen is about 12.1.0 ng-bootstrap version)?

Comment: @Eliseo fullscreen: true is added already while opening modal
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwqusl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal-component.ts
can you check this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the stackblitz, I think the issue is due to `view encapsulation` - being set as `none`, so css didn't get applied.

In Angular usually the html element with the component selector `ngbd-modal-content` will not take the height of the parent, we need to manually adjust it with css, its a pain point of angular!

```
// encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, // <- remove this
styles: [
    `
    :host {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0; 
      border: solid 3px yellow; /* for debugging purposes */
    }
  `,
  ],
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwqusl-y557ah)